# Websocket Connection on localhost

Tags: websocket, phpwebsocket

im trying to create the WebSocket connection on localhost. but it is not working.
when I'm connecting it on HTTP connection and use ws then it is working properly.

URL http://192.168.18.101/
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kw0xJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMsA2.png)

but when im using HTTPS and WSS it is not create the WebSocket connection

https://192.168.18.101/
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvIEZ.png)

i have also assigned the self-assigned SSL cert.

I'm using apache2 on Ubuntu 18.04.
actually, i want to deploy my project on Premises server.

this vhost configration for http

on my local server on http request ws websocket is working.
but when im try to https usign wss it is not connecting.

Comment: Your screenshot shows the `HTTPS` version of `localhost` is not secure. Did you actually configure a (self-signed) SSL certificate?